# Parameter Passing values into my Class in python/Pygame

Tags: python

I have a class in Python that will be for the spawning of NPC's in a small space. I want to pass the information (such as the location for their image/sprite, their co-ordinates where they'll spawn, etc.) into the class:

```
class NPC(object):
        def __init__(self, img, x, y):
                self.image = pygame.image.load(img).convert_alpha()
                self.x = x
                self.y = y
```

I want the values img, x and y to be passed in but I cannot think of a suitable method of doing so, as the **init** function for some reason cannot be called.

I feel that the solution is staring me right in the face but I don't know how to get to it.

Comment: you can make a method update(x, y) to update these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you say that the init cannot be called?  To run the built in function **init** you just write:

```
joe = NPC(joe_image, joe_x, joe_y)
```

If joe already exists and you want to respawn him, just copy init as another function:

```
def respawn(self,(self, x, y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
```

and call:

```
joe.respawn(joe_x, joe_y)
```

[I'm assuming you don't need to change his image here]

Comment: hi Stephen, thanks for the help! However, for some reason, when I try to do this method I get an error stating this:
    "self.image = pygame.image.load(path).convert_alpha()
pygame.error: No video mode has been set"
(path is the holder of what would be "joe_image" in the function)

Comment: @Polybrow this is another problem, so it belongs to another question. SO is not a forum, it's a QA technical knowledge base.

Comment: "just copy init as another function" : PLEASE DONT !!! Call this other function from `__init__` instead.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - good comment, it is good practice never to copy-paste.